# Why can't create array of ObservableField?

Tags: java, android, observable

I can create and use array of ObservableBoolean like this :

```
public ObservableBoolean[] isPhotoVisible = {
            new ObservableBoolean(),
            new ObservableBoolean(),
            new ObservableBoolean(),
            new ObservableBoolean(),
            new ObservableBoolean(),
            new ObservableBoolean()};
```

But why I can't create array of ObservableField like this? It can't compile and says `Generic Array Creation` :

```
public ObservableField<String>[] idFilePath = {new ObservableField<>()};
```

Comment: A google search for the compile error leads to this blog post that explains the issue: http://www.tothenew.com/blog/why-is-generic-array-creation-not-allowed-in-java/

Comment: Great, please post this as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Google search for the compile error leads to this blog post that explains the issue: http://www.tothenew.com/blog/why-is-generic-array-creation-not-allowed-in-java/